# Create volume backup of Jenkins in Docker

Tags: docker, jenkins

I have a Jenkins installation in Docker and I need to create backups and restore them when I need.
I tried some plugins but because I'm using docker they don't work. Besides that, I need to backup everything including historic.

I stumbled on this page: https://medium.com/pacroy/how-to-backup-and-restore-your-jenkins-data-volume-in-docker-2ac66d99315a

but the instructions are for windows and I can't adapt that to my linux environment.

My question is: how can I create full backups of my jenkins instance in docker in a way that I can restore it or even create a copy in another machine.

Answer (score 7):

All the Jenkins data including job configuration and builds are stored under `/var/jenkins_home` inside the container.

Thus you can simply backup this folder and all the Jenkins state will be persisted. You can regularly copy this folder from the container using:

```
docker cp <jenkins-container-name>:/var/jenkins_home ./jenkins_home
```

You from anyone of these backup you can start a new jenkins instance using the command:

```
docker run -v ./jenkins_volume:/var/jenkins_home -p 8080:8080 jenkins ...
```

Comment: I tried your first command and it's a simple backup of my jenkins_home folder. I copied that folder to another machine and I want to create a jenkins instance there. What does it mean the ./jenkins_volume in the second command?

Comment: Btw, I used the following command to create the jenkins instance in the first place: docker container run --name jenkins -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 -v $HOME/jenkins:/var/jenkins_home -d jenkins

Comment: @zephirus `./jenkins_volume` means path to the backup

Comment: The first command copies the `/var/jenkins_home` to some arbitrary folder - it does not really matter where it goes.  The second command would be executed if the first jenkins instance failed and you wanted to start a new one with the backup data.  It does not matter where you put the backup data as long as you restore from the same place.

Comment: I would recommend looking at `docker pause` and `docker unpause` or `docker-lvm-volume plugin` in conjunction with this answer.  You can create snapshots of volumes.

Comment: My backup folder is "\home\jenkinsBackup". So the second command is only if I want to restore jenkins on the same machine where it was before? My usecase would be to make a complete copy to other machine. I tried creating the backup in the same folder structure on the second machine and the I run: docker run -v /home/jenkinsBackup:/var/jenkins_home -p 8080:8080 jenkins. I get this error: Can not write to /var/jenkins_home/copy_reference_file.log. Wrong volume permissions?

Answer (score 1):

My user is admin, my backup folder is data. 
After copying jenkins backupfolder to new place you need change owner and start as usual (my example is on docker-compose)

```
sudo chown admin:admin docker-compose.yml 
sudo chown -R 1000:1000 data/
```

official dockerfile - [link](https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker/blob/83ce6f6070f1670563a00d0f61d04edd62b78f4f/Dockerfile#L8) - Jenkins is run with user `jenkins`, uid = 1000

[docker hub](https://hub.docker.com/_/jenkins/)