# Jenkins backup when restored getting an error

Tags: docker, jenkins

I am trying to backup my Jenkins which is running on a docker container. I had referred a stack overflow

[Reference used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51067300/create-volume-backup-of-jenkins-in-docker)

So as said suggested by the first answer I took a backup using backup plugin then I used docker cp command to copy to the host.

```
docker cp 2620d31f3b67:/Users/sidharth/jenkins_vol.zip .
```

Once this was done I unzipped the file and then ran the docker run command and tried to mount the volume

`docker run -v ./jenkins_vol:/var/jenkins_home -p 8080:8080 jenkins/jenkins:lts`

but I got the below error:

```
sidharth@Sidharths-MacBook-Air ~ % docker run -v /Users/sidharth/jenkins_vol:/var/jenkins_home -p 8080:8080 jenkins/jenkins:lts
Running from: /usr/share/jenkins/jenkins.war
webroot: EnvVars.masterEnvVars.get("JENKINS_HOME")
2023-02-25 08:07:32.364+0000 [id=1] INFO    org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Log#initialized: Logging initialized @325ms to org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.JavaUtilLog
2023-02-25 08:07:32.402+0000 [id=1] INFO    winstone.Logger#logInternal: Beginning extraction from war file
2023-02-25 08:07:57.594+0000 [id=1] WARNING o.e.j.s.handler.ContextHandler#setContextPath: Empty contextPath
2023-02-25 08:07:57.637+0000 [id=1] INFO    org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server#doStart: jetty-9.4.45.v20220203; built: 2022-02-03T09:14:34.105Z; git: 4a0c91c0be53805e3fcffdcdcc9587d5301863db; jvm 11.0.16+8
2023-02-25 08:07:58.367+0000 [id=1] INFO    o.e.j.w.StandardDescriptorProcessor#visitServlet: NO JSP Support for /, did not find org.eclipse.jetty.jsp.JettyJspServlet
2023-02-25 08:07:58.463+0000 [id=1] INFO    o.e.j.s.s.DefaultSessionIdManager#doStart: DefaultSessionIdManager workerName=node0
2023-02-25 08:07:58.463+0000 [id=1] INFO    o.e.j.s.s.DefaultSessionIdManager#doStart: No SessionScavenger set, using defaults
2023-02-25 08:07:58.464+0000 [id=1] INFO    o.e.j.server.session.HouseKeeper#startScavenging: node0 Scavenging every 660000ms
2023-02-25 08:07:59.989+0000 [id=1] INFO    hudson.WebAppMain#contextInitialized: Jenkins home directory: /var/jenkins_home found at: EnvVars.masterEnvVars.get("JENKINS_HOME")
2023-02-25 08:08:00.453+0000 [id=1] INFO    o.e.j.s.handler.ContextHandler#doStart: Started w.@73a19967{Jenkins v2.346.3,/,file:///var/jenkins_home/war/,AVAILABLE}{/var/jenkins_home/war}
2023-02-25 08:08:00.469+0000 [id=1] INFO    o.e.j.server.AbstractConnector#doStart: Started ServerConnector@39a8312f{HTTP/1.1, (http/1.1)}{0.0.0.0:8080}
2023-02-25 08:08:00.469+0000 [id=1] INFO    org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server#doStart: Started @28440ms
2023-02-25 08:08:00.470+0000 [id=24]    INFO    winstone.Logger#logInternal: Winstone Servlet Engine running: controlPort=disabled
2023-02-25 08:08:01.436+0000 [id=30]    INFO    jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1#onAttained: Started initialization
2023-02-25 08:08:01.555+0000 [id=32]    INFO    jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1#onAttained: Listed all plugins
2023-02-25 08:08:04.001+0000 [id=35]    INFO    jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1#onAttained: Prepared all plugins
2023-02-25 08:08:04.014+0000 [id=30]    INFO    jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1#onAttained: Started all plugins
2023-02-25 08:08:04.041+0000 [id=31]    INFO    jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1#onAttained: Augmented all extensions
2023-02-25 08:08:04.223+0000 [id=34]    SEVERE  jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1#onTaskFailed: Failed Loading global config
com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CannotResolveClassException: hudson.security.GlobalMatrixAuthorizationStrategy
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.DefaultMapper.realClass(DefaultMapper.java:81)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:125)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.DynamicProxyMapper.realClass(DynamicProxyMapper.java:55)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:125)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.PackageAliasingMapper.realClass(PackageAliasingMapper.java:88)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:125)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.ClassAliasingMapper.realClass(ClassAliasingMapper.java:79)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:125)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.ArrayMapper.realClass(ArrayMapper.java:74)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:125)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.SecurityMapper.realClass(SecurityMapper.java:71)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:125)
    at hudson.util.XStream2$CompatibilityMapper.realClass(XStream2.java:411)
    at hudson.util.xstream.MapperDelegate.realClass(MapperDelegate.java:46)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:125)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CachingMapper.realClass(CachingMapper.java:47)
    at hudson.util.RobustReflectionConverter.determineType(RobustReflectionConverter.java:521)
    at hudson.util.RobustReflectionConverter.doUnmarshal(RobustReflectionConverter.java:346)
Caused: jenkins.util.xstream.CriticalXStreamException: 
---- Debugging information ----
cause-exception     : com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CannotResolveClassException
cause-message       : hudson.security.GlobalMatrixAuthorizationStrategy
class               : hudson.model.Hudson
required-type       : hudson.model.Hudson
converter-type      : hudson.util.RobustReflectionConverter
path                : /hudson/authorizationStrategy
line number         : 10
version             : not available
-------------------------------
    at hudson.util.RobustReflectionConverter.doUnmarshal(RobustReflectionConverter.java:381)
    at hudson.util.RobustReflectionConverter.unmarshal(RobustReflectionConverter.java:289)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:74)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.java:72)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:68)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:52)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.start(TreeUnmarshaller.java:136)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractTreeMarshallingStrategy.unmarshal(AbstractTreeMarshallingStrategy.java:32)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.unmarshal(XStream.java:1421)
    at hudson.util.XStream2.unmarshal(XStream2.java:189)
    at hudson.util.XStream2.unmarshal(XStream2.java:160)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.unmarshal(XStream.java:1399)
    at hudson.XmlFile.unmarshal(XmlFile.java:196)
Caused: java.io.IOException: Unable to read /var/jenkins_home/config.xml
```

Comment: `Unable to read /var/jenkins_home/config.xml` <= did you check that the user inside the container is able to access your bind mount after you restored the files?

Comment: How could i check this ? Will it be some permission issue ?

Comment: The answer is in the link you provided in your question.

Comment: But like I said it does not seem to work. When I run Jenkins again I lost all the jobs and even the password seems to be different,